# By clicking an item in IFrame (Inline Frame) i need to route to specific URL

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular2-router3

Hi am using i frame in one component of my angular 2 application.

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeResourceUrl,DomSanitizer,} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'sample comp',
  templateUrl: './sample-comp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-comp.component.css']
})
export class sampleComp implements OnInit {
  //DECLARATION
  webURL:SafeResourceUrl;
  constructor() { 

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
public onSelectid(){
  console.log('Router selected');

}
}
let greeter = new CampaignOrderComponent();
module FooModule {  
    export var FooInstance = new CampaignOrderComponent();
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<iframe src="http://sampleurl" width="100%" height="600" style="margin-top:-10px" frameborder="0"
    webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

While triggering a click event on i frame, i need to route to another component.(which i had already specified at my root component's routing file).

Right now **inside the i frame app**(a mvc app) i had triggered a click function

```
parrent.showme()
```

and added  index.js on root folder of angular 2 app (linked with index.html)

**index.js**

```
  function showme()
  {
       alert('function called');
       FooModule.FooInstance.onSelectid();

  }
```

now i can show alert on the angular 2 app page via clicking inside the i frame app.

**The target is to change the functionality of the showme() to change the route of the angular 2 app.**

**How can i do it ?**

i had tried several methods to solve it, unfortunately i cant get any.

Answer (score 1):

Add id to your frame and then use contentWindow.document.body.onclick on iframe element

```
   <iframe id="iframe_id" src="https://sampleurl" style="margin-top:-10px" frameborder="1"
        webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
    </iframe>

 constructor(private _router: Router){
  } 
  ngAfterViewInit(){
    document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
      () => {
      this._router.navigate(['/yourChildRoute']);
      }


   }
```

Comment: hi,
what all components need to import before using this code ? 
(expect ngAfterViewInit)

Comment: ngAfterViewInit will trigger once DOM is initialized

Comment: Please check [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7rUpBQFjlo5VHhofgPbM?p=preview)

Comment: Please use [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/7rUpBQFjlo5VHhofgPbM?p=preview) and do above changes.

Comment: this plunkr only saying about routing and all.
notheing about other criterias

Comment: please add above mentioned changes in app.component.ts and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125100/discussion-between-aswin-kv-and-sudheer-kb).

Comment: i had made some changes to the function can you please go though it